# React Native: Unable to set image uri within FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, wordpress-rest-api, react-flatlist

I am trying to access */wp-json/wp/v2/media/* wordpress API and get uri of image from *guid.rendered* and set it to Image inside FlatList but getting following error

> you attempted to set the key _v with the value 1 on an object that is meant to be immutable an is frozen.

Home.js

```
return(
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
    <View>
           {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : (
     <FlatList 
     onRefresh={onRefresh}
     refreshing={isFetching}
      data={post}
      keyExtractor={({ id },index) => id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Alert.alert('Blog reader feature will be available soon!')}>
          <View style={{padding:5,backgroundColor:'#3578e5',margin:5}}>
            <Image style={{width:Dimensions.width,height:250}} source={{
              uri: getBlogPostsImage(item.featured_media)
            }}/>
          <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'#fff',fontSize:20,marginTop:5}}>{item.title.rendered}</Text>
          <Text style={{color:'#fff',marginTop:5}}>{item.date}</Text>
          <RenderHtml source={getContent(item)} tagsStyles={tagsStyles} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
    />
  )}
  </View>
  </SafeAreaView>   
);
```

getBlogPostsImage()

```
const getBlogPostsImage = async (id) => {
  try {
   const response = await fetch('http://wp.devlops.xyz/wp-json/wp/v2/media/'+id);
   const jsonPostImage = await response.json();
   return jsonPostImage.guid.rendered;
 } catch (error) {
   Alert.alert("Failed to load image");
 }
```

}

I also tried fetching if the featured image exists but that too didn't work

```
{item.featured_media>0 ? <Image style={{width:Dimensions.width,height:250}} source={{
              uri: getBlogPostsImage(item.featured_media)
            }}/>:null}
```

**UPDATE**

Using solution provided [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241271/wp-rest-api-details-of-latest-post-including-featured-media-url-in-one-request/249769#249769?newreg=0ee207dc439c466e8a0dd0f486e94027) the URI now appears in */wp-json/wp/v2/posts/id* but wont get fetched!

Updated Flatlist

```
<FlatList 
     onRefresh={onRefresh}
     refreshing={isFetching}
      data={post}
      keyExtractor={({ id },index) => id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{padding:5,backgroundColor:'#3578e5',margin:5}}>
            {item.featured_media>0?<Image style={{width:Dimensions.width,height:250}} source={{
              uri: item.featured_media_uri
            }}/>:null}
          <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'#fff',fontSize:20,marginTop:5}}>{item.title.rendered}</Text>
          <Text style={{color:'#fff',marginTop:10}}>{item.date}</Text>
          <RenderHtml source={getContent(item)} tagsStyles={tagsStyles} />
          </View>
         
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
      )
    }
    />
```

Comment: you can't pass a promise to `source={{
              uri: getBlogPostsImage(item.featured_media)
            }}`, make a new component and control the lifecycle for that api call

Comment: @Horst any guide i can refer?

Comment: @Horst you want me to make blog list items as a separate component, pass title,date and image uri as props to it?

Comment: for now, you are passing a function into the `uri`, which is a async function and would return a promise to `uri`

Comment: Assume I created a component, will I be able to pass URI as props to it using the same technique? @Horst

Comment: your domain doesn't support https and clear text traffic is disabled in RN by default